# Twitter sentiment analysis on a string

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I've written a program that takes a twitter data that contains tweets and labels (`0` for neutral sentiment and `1` for negative sentiment) and predicts which category the tweet belongs to.
The program works well on the training and test Set. However I'm having problem in applying prediction function with  a string. I'm not sure how to do that.

I have tried cleaning the string the way I cleaned the dataset before calling the predict function but the values returned are in wrong shape.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
ps = PorterStemmer()
import re

#Loading dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('tweet.csv')

#List to hold cleaned tweets
clean_tweet = []

#Cleaning tweets
for i in range(len(dataset)):
    tweet = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', dataset['tweet'][i])
    tweet = re.sub('@[\w]*',' ',dataset['tweet'][i])
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    tweet = tweet.split()
    tweet = [ps.stem(token) for token in tweet if not token in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    tweet = ' '.join(tweet)
    clean_tweet.append(tweet)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 3000)
X = cv.fit_transform(clean_tweet)
X =  X.toarray()
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
n_b = GaussianNB()
n_b.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred  = n_b.predict(X_test) 

some_tweet = "this is a mean tweet"  # How to apply predict function to this string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cv.transform([cleaned_new_tweet])` on your new string to transform your new Tweet to your existing document-term matrix. That will return the Tweet in the correct shape.

Comment: `cv.transform()` on my new string gives me an error - `ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.`

Comment: Sorry, cv.transform() takes an object of type iterable, so you will need to add the new_tweet part of an iterable. I've updated the answer and that should work.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. However can you tell me why `cv.fit_transform()`  would be wrong here ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38692520/what-is-the-difference-between-fit-transform-and-transform-in-sklearn-countvecto this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

`.predict()` expects a `list` of `strings`. So you need to add `some_tweet` to a `list`. E.g. `new_tweet = ["this is a mean tweet"]`

## Your code

You had some issues in your code that I tried fixing for you...

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
ps = PorterStemmer()
import re

#Loading dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('tweet.csv')


# Define cleaning function
# You can define it once as a function so it can be easily re-used else where
def clean_tweet(tweet: str):
    tweet = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', dataset['tweet'][i])
    tweet = re.sub('@[\w]*', ' ', tweet) #BUG: you need to pass the tweet you modified here instead of the original tweet again
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    tweet = tweet.split()
    tweet = [ps.stem(token) for token in tweet if not token in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    tweet = ' '.join(tweet)
    return tweet

#List to hold cleaned tweets and labels
X = [clean_tweet(tweet) for tweet in dataset['tweet']] # you can create your X directly with your new function
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

# Define a single model
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# Use Pipeline as your classifier, this way you don't need to keep calling a transform and fit all the time.
classifier = Pipeline(
    [
        ('cv', CountVectorizer(max_features=300)),
        ('n_b', GaussianNB())
    ]
)


# Before you trained your CountVectorizer BEFORE splitting into train/test. That is a biiig mistake.
# First you split to train/split and then you train all the steps of your model.

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

# Here you train all steps of your Pipeline in one go.
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred  = classifier.predict(X_test)


# Predicting new tweets
some_tweet = "this is a mean tweet"
some_tweet = clean_tweet(some_tweet) # re-use your clean function
predicted = classifier.predict([some_tweet]) # put the tweet inside a list!!!!
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Can you share a good resource on the Pipeline that you mentioned. I am new to this I haven't  learned that yet. Also does splitting increase any performance or it just helps  later in calculating various scores and accuracies

Comment: [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33008/is-it-always-better-to-use-the-whole-dataset-to-train-the-final-model) goes into a good amount of detail on training/test splits.