# Mismatch dimension error when trying to predict using naive bayes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-processing, naivebayes

I am struggling with a dimension error when I try to predict using naive bayes classifier.

The data consists of a column for sentences and then a column for sentiments (aka labels). I want to use a naive bayes classifier to predict the sentiment of each sentence.

I start off with separating out testing, training and validation data sets

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import (CountVectorizer,TfidfVectorizer, TfidfTransformer)
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2

training_set,sentence_split_further,training_set_sentiments,sentiments_split_further=train_test_split(sentence_data.Sentence,sentence_data.Sentiment,test_size=.5, train_size=.5, random_state=1)

testing_set,validation_set,testing_set_sentiments,validation_set_sentiments=train_test_split(sentence_split_further,sentiments_split_further,test_size=.5, train_size=.5, random_state=1)
```

Then I create a feature matrix, apply tfid and prune the best k words. I did this all in a function that I created called feature_selection_vector

```
tfidf_testing_feature_matrix=feature_selection_vector(testing_set,testing_set_sentiments)
tfidf_validation_feature_matrix=feature_selection_vector(validation_set,validation_set_sentiments)
```

Here is the code for the `feature_selection_vector` function

```
def feature_selection_vector( sentence_data, sentiments ):
    #creates the feature vector and calculates tfid
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', 
                                  token_pattern=r'\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b',  
                                  ngram_range=(1, 1) 
                                  )  
    count_vectorized = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentence_data)
    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(smooth_idf=True, use_idf=True)
    vectorized = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(count_vectorized)
    
    vector=pd.DataFrame(vectorized.toarray(), 
                 index=['sentence '+str(i) 
                        for i in range(1, 1+len(sentence_data))],
                 columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
    selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000)
    selector.fit(vector, sentiments)
    return vector
```

Now I want to fit the Naive Bayes Classifier with training data and then use the model to predict using testing data.

```
naive_bayes = MultinomialNB()
naive_bayes.fit(tfidf_training_feature_matrix,training_set_sentiments)
NBC_tfidf_sentiment_predicted=naive_bayes.predict(tfidf_testing_feature_matrix)
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 892 is different from 348)
```

The two sizes it is complaining about is number of columns of the training set (892) and the number of columns of the testing set (348)

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** use `fit_transform` to get features for the validation and test sets, as you do here (using your `feature_selection_vector()` function).

`fit_transform` is used only once with the **training** data; for the validation and test ones, simple `transform` should be used instead, using the existing `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfTransformer` as they have already been fitted to the **training** data.

In your code, both the `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfTransformer` are fitted again with the validation and test data, leading to different number of features, and eventually to the expected error you report.

For more details, see [What is the difference between fit_transform and transform in sklearn countvectorizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38692520/what-is-the-difference-between-fit-transform-and-transform-in-sklearn-countvecto)

You should seriously think wrapping up all the stages in a [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html).